# UIAutomation as an alternative to SendKeys - handing pop-ups

Tags: delphi, ui-automation

I'm just dipping my toe into UIAutomation as a replacement for the usual SendKeys stuff to send keystrokes to another application from a testbed I'm writing in D7.

Fwiw, I'm not sure that this is the correct terminology, but so far as I know the target application doesn't actively "support" UIAutomation in the sense that, say, Adobe Acrobat does:  What I mean is that when you query Acrobat via UIAutomation, it detects that you are and pops up a series of dialogs offering to help set up its accessibility assistance.  My target app seemingly isn't "UIAutomation-aware" in that way.  Anyway ...

I'm stuck at the point where I provoke the target app into popping up a modal dialog for data input.  This pop-up doesn't seem to be accessible via the target's UIAutomation tree.  OTOH, I can find its window handle via EnumWindows easily enough.  So I could retrieve the UIAutomation tree for the pop-up and work with that to fill in the data it's asking for, I imagine.

However, and this is the substance of my q, I'm wondering whether I'm missing a trick not being able to find the pop-up dialog by a recursive inspection of the tree elements of the target app's UIAutomation tree, or whether needing to hop to another tree to fill in a pop-up dialog is just part of the UIAutomation paradigm?  (It seems unlikely that the UIAutomation framework could "know" that an app and a pop-up are related, but I thought I'd check).

In case it's of interest, the target application in my case is actually the D7 IDE itself, though it could be XE4 or XE6, which I also have.  I'm doing this to see if I can devise an answer to another SO question.  What the OP asked there would have been doable in 5 minutes if Delphi presented its OTA services via an automation interface - seems odd that the best tool for putting together automation interfaces doesn't** have one of its own.  I wonder why not? I imagine it might be objected to as off-topic to ask that here, although some contributors here would be in a position to know the answer rather than just speculate.  Maybe I'll ask on the EMB NGs when they're back up.

** Update:  I just noticed a cryptic mention in the OTA chapter of the D5 Developer's Guide that "[the OTA] interfaces can be used by any programming language that supports COM".  I wonder if they mean, from an external app?

Comment: Not, OTA is in-proc only. What it means is that you can write an add-in DLL that will be loaded by the IDE and can use the COM OTA interfaces.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Thanks, I'm glad you said that, because an add-in was what I've been imagining I would need to do, which was why I was asking about message loops in DLLs the other day, so I could see if I could communicate with it from outside.